# flash media server FMS 3.5 and IIS on same machine

Tags: flash, video-streaming, flash-media-server, fms3

We are deploying a media management system within a local network. FMS will be used to serve the media within the local network. Since we will only have max 100 users and we have a powerful dual 4 core xeon and the plan was to install IIS and FMS on the same machine. But now I read that there will be a conflict because the embedded Apache server that FMS installs will fight for port 80 with IIS.

So one possible solution: I've been reading in the Adobe docs that RTMP is far more efficient than tunneling through HTTP, so if we make sure all client machines allow RTMP (firewall exception) can we then change the configured Apache port and assume that Apache will never ever be used?

Heck in this case can we configure FMS and choose not to install Apache at all and be OK?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a second IP address
There is complete manual which help me in same situation
http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/iis7-post-44-iis7-and-apache-on-the-same-machine